# Discord.js 'awaitReactions is not a function' error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to have a bot react when users click the emojis on the bot's embeds.

I'm receiving in the console:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: chestEmbed.awaitReactions
> is not a function

The code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'enterhouse',
    aliases: 'eh',
    permissions: ["ADMINISTRATOR", "MANAGE_MESSAGES", "CONNECT"],
    description: "Pick a number",
    async execute(client, message, args, Discord){

        const chestEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#FFA500')
        .setImage('https://imageURL.jpg');

        message.channel.send(chestEmbed).then(chestEmbed => {chestEmbed.react('1️⃣').then(() => chestEmbed.react('2️⃣').then(() => chestEmbed.react('3️⃣')))}
          )
        .catch(() => console.error('One of the emojis failed to react.'));

        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return (['1️⃣', '2️⃣', '3️⃣'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id);
        };

        chestEmbed.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
            .then(collected => {
                const reaction = collected.first();

                if (reaction.emoji.name === '1️⃣') {
                    chestEmbed.delete();
                    message.reply('you reacted with 1');
                } else if (reaction.emoji.name === '2️⃣') {
                    message.reply('you reacted with 2');
                } else {
                    message.reply('you reacted with 3');
                }
            })
            .catch(collected => {
                message.reply('Time is up, you did not react.');
            });
    }
}
```

It worked fine when it was message.awaitReactions instead.

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are awaiting messages from the embed it's self not the message the embed is in.
Simple fix:

```js
...
chestEmbed = await message.channel.send(chestEmbed)
...
```

Full Code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'enterhouse',
    aliases: 'eh',
    permissions: ["ADMINISTRATOR", "MANAGE_MESSAGES", "CONNECT"],
    description: "Pick a number",
    async execute(client, message, args, Discord) {
        const chestEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#FFA500')
        .setImage('https://imageURL.jpg');

        chestEmbed = await message.channel.send(chestEmbed)
        chestEmbed.react('1️⃣').then(() => chestEmbed.react('2️⃣')).then(() => chestEmbed.react('3️⃣'))

        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return (['1️⃣', '2️⃣', '3️⃣'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id);
        };

        chestEmbed.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
          .then(collected => {
              const reaction = collected.first();

               if (reaction.emoji.name === '1️⃣') {
                   chestEmbed.delete();
                   message.reply('you reacted with 1');
               } else if (reaction.emoji.name === '2️⃣') {
                   message.reply('you reacted with 2');
               } else {
                   message.reply('you reacted with 3');
               }
          })
          .catch(collected => {
              message.reply('Time is up, you did not react.');
          });
    }
}
```